# Differences between window.onkeypress vs window.document.body.onkeypress

Tags: javascript

I inherited this JavaScript code which reads in the input key event and process them, however I am getting duplicate for each key pressed.

Intelisense shows "window" as

> var window: Window & typeof globalThis

```
    this.listen = function() {

       //when comment one of these two out, my duplicate issue goes away.
       window.onkeypress = this.captureKeyPress;  
       window.document.body.onkeypress = this.captureKeyPress;
    }


    this.captureKeyPress = function(e) {
       //process key input event
    }
```

I researched around but I cannot seem to find the different between **window.keypress** and **window.document.body.onkeypress**.  Some of the resource about key press event refers to  GlobalEventHandlers.onkeypress or document.onkeypress.

Can someone  point me to the document or resource talking about these two events and their differences? I have a feeling they implemented this way due to supporting legacy browser such as IE7 or IE9 and earlier.

Comment: The event is the same they are just applied to different things, ie one is applied to the whole window while the other is only applied to the `<body>` element

Comment: Ah, the find times we had on https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html in the past.

Comment: FYI `onkeypress` has a Deprecated warning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Document.body property represents the  or  node of the current document, or null if no such element exists.

> A global variable, window, representing the window in which the script is running, is exposed to JavaScript code.

basically `window.document.body` refers to the body tag while `window` is all the file.
as for supporting legacy browsers such as IE7 or IE9 and earlier - `window` is supporting IE4 and above while `Document.body` supports IE6 and above. either way IE7 and above is fine with the event.

### sources

[Document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)

[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Answer (score 1):

They work the same in Chrome at least - one is on the window the other on the body

```js
window.onkeypress = function(e) { console.log("okp",e.key) }
window.document.body.onkeypress = function(e) { console.log("dbokp",e.key) }
```

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the difference between document and window objects](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/#:%7E:text=Good%20question.&text=Well%2C%20the%20window%20is%20the,gets%20loaded%20into%20the%20browser.&text=The%20document%20object%20is%20your,%2C%20URL%2C%20cookie%2C%20etc.)

The difference is that with `window.onkeypress` you are registering an event on the window object and with `window.document.body.onkeypress`you are registering an event on the body. An event will trigger for a specific element when it is in focus. However an event registered to that elements parent element will also trigger, hence an event registered to the window will trigger either way, and so do the ones registered on the document or body.

See [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/sazelurivi/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
window.onkeypress = function() {
  console.log('key pressed window')
}

window.document.body.onkeypress = function() {
  console.log('key pressed body')
}

document.getElementById('div').onkeypress = function() {
  console.log('key pressed div');
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```